# Simple Factor Class

Tags: c++, recursion, primes, dynamic-programming, factors

I have a class which lazily factors numbers. It provides the user with these methods:

1. `getFactors` returns a `vector<unsigned int>` containing the argument's factors
2. `getFactorCount` returns the number of an argument's factors
3. `compareFactors` takes 2 arguments returning a negative integer if the 1<sup>st</sup> argument has fewer factors, a positive number if the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument has fewer factors, and a 0 if the arguments have the same number of factors
4. `findNextPrime` returns the next prime after the current number
5. `gcd` returns the Greatest Common Denominator of its arguments
6. `lcm` returns the Least Common Multiple of its arguments

I welcome general advice on the class, but I have specific concerns in these areas:

1. I'm varying a lot of extra memory to maintain the index of a numbers next factor as the my `vector` becomes large
2. I have to reconstruct the `vector` of factors for every method I provide that seems expensive time wise

Is there a way that I could structure my data differently to avoid such costs?

---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Factor {
    vector<pair<unsigned int, size_t>> factors;

    void factor(const unsigned int input) {
        auto i = 2U;

        while (input % i != 0U) {
            ++i;
        }

        const auto second = input / i;

        factors[input] = make_pair(i, second);

        if (second >= 2 && factors[second].first == 0U) {
            factor(second);
        }
    }
public:
    vector<unsigned int> getFactors(unsigned int input) {
        if (input <= 1) {
            return vector<unsigned int>{};
        } else if (input >= size(factors)) {
            factors.resize(input + 1U);
            factor(input);
        } else if (factors[input].first == 0U) {
            factor(input);
        }

        vector<unsigned int> result;

        do {
            result.push_back(factors[input].first);
            input = factors[input].second;
        } while (factors[input].first != 0U);

        return result;
    }

    size_t getFactorCount(const unsigned int input) {
        return size(getFactors(input));
    }

    int compareFactors(const unsigned int lhs, const unsigned int rhs) {
        return getFactorCount(lhs) - getFactorCount(rhs);
    }

    unsigned int findNextPrime(unsigned int input) {
        if (++input == 1U) {
            return 1U;
        }

        do {
            if (input >= size(factors)) {
                factors.resize(input + 1U);
            }

            if (factors[input].first == 0U) {
                factor(input);
            }
        } while (factors[input++].second != 1U);

        return input - 1U;
    }

    unsigned int gcd(const unsigned int lhs, const unsigned int rhs) {
        vector<unsigned int> result;
        const vector<unsigned int> lhsFactors = getFactors(lhs);
        const vector<unsigned int> rhsFactors = getFactors(rhs);

        set_intersection(cbegin(lhsFactors), cend(lhsFactors), cbegin(rhsFactors), cend(rhsFactors), back_inserter(result));

        return accumulate(cbegin(result), cend(result), 1U, multiplies<unsigned int>());
    }

    unsigned int lcm(const unsigned int lhs, const unsigned int rhs) {
        const vector<unsigned int> lhsFactors = getFactors(lhs);
        const vector<unsigned int> rhsFactors = getFactors(rhs);
        const auto it = find_first_of(cbegin(lhsFactors), cend(lhsFactors), cbegin(rhsFactors), cend(rhsFactors));

        return it == cend(lhsFactors) ? 1U : *it;
    }
};
```

I've included some testing demonstrating class functionality here: http://ideone.com/njH34A

Answer (score 1):

- I think that adding `U` obfuscates the code

Two remarks regarding algorithms for `gcd` and `lcm`. I think much more readable would be :

```
int gcd(int lhs, int rhs)
{
    if (lhs == 0) return rhs;
    return gcd(rhs % lhs, lhs);
}


int lcm(int lhs, int rhs)
{
    int temp = gcd(lhs, rhs);
    return temp ? (lhs / temp * rhs) : 0;
}
```

- If you can use `auto`, then do it where it can make code more
  readable, e.g. `const vector<unsigned int>`
- I would also take a closer look at `factor` method - it is not very
  efficient. I think you don't have to check `i` to value greater than `sqrt(input)` and maybe consider using some kind of sieve (you could google the general idea), but I would first deal with other problems.
- Resizing looks sketchy...

Great you want to use `std` !

Comment: Hmmm... I felt as though `factor` was the one thing in the whole class that *was* efficient. Why do you say it's inefficient? I may be misinterpreting your comment, but you know it's lazily populated, right? For example if I `factor` 4, 8, and 10, 3 will never be populated.

Comment: @JonathanMee as a general note, lazily populated != efficient (and in fact it isn't uncommon for it to mean that the computation is inefficient, or at least slow, so execution is deferred until such time as it needs to be done).

Comment: @Dannnno Really? You got a source for that relative to number factorization? That just sounds crazy to me, if I factor 1 large number, and the rest of my numbers are under 100 all the sudden I have to fill the entire `vector<vector<pair<int, size_t>>`?

Comment: @JonathanMee Besides common sense? No. In general, lazy initialization is really just deferred execution - it has nothing to do with how efficient that execution will be whenever it runs. Not doing more calculations than you need to when you need to is good, and is more efficient than the alternative, but lazy initialization isn't sufficient to call your algorithm "efficient".